# unable to return out parameter value from oracle to c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have table in oracle that consists of different columns  username, password, attempts, agree, admin, and lock date.
 Username and pwd are input parameters and rest of the others are output paramters.If the username and pwd that is in the database  exists , I have to return login status Y else N. 
Also I need to get value of outparmeters such as  attempss, agree, admin etc. When I exeute stored proc in oracle, the out put is fine, I am not  able to populate it in C#. 
Here is my code.
I am using login control of asp.net(login.aspx)

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
 {

     string username = Server.HtmlEncode(Login1.UserName);
     string pwd = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Login1.Password)

     var isUserValid = userbll.ValidateUser(username, pwd, out userInfo);
     //calling function to bll.
```

Userinfo is a separate class  has all properties (name, pwd,attempt,agree, admin etc)  and I passed userinfo as out parameter

userBLL.css

```
public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password, out UserInfo userInfo)

    {
       string vLoginStatus=dataClass.ValidateUser(username, password, out userInfo);

       if (vLoginStatus == "Y")
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
```

DLL code

```
internal string ValidateUser(string username, string password, out UserInfo userInfo)

    {
        OracleParameter[] p = 
        {
            OracleHelper.MakeInParam("in_username", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20, username),
            OracleHelper.MakeInParam("in_password", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32, password),
            OracleHelper.MakeOutParam("out_Login_ok", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1),

            OracleHelper.MakeOutParam("out_admin", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1),
            OracleHelper.MakeOutParam("out_agree", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1),

            OracleHelper.MakeOutParam("out_type", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2),
            OracleHelper.MakeOutParam("out_locked", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1),

            OracleHelper.MakeOutParam("out_errornumber", OracleDbType.Int32, 0)
        };

        OracleHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(OraClientConnectionString,
               CommandType.StoredProcedure,
          string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", Schema, PackageName, "stored proc Name"), p);


         var vLoginStatus = ((OracleParameter)p[2]).Value.ToString();
        userInfo = new UserInfo
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password,

            Admin = ((OracleParameter)p[3]).Value.ToString(),
            Agree = HrOracleHelper.ConvertToBoolean(((OracleParameter)p[4]).Value.ToString()), // hrhelper is just a class to change agree and locekd to boolean

            Locked = HrOracleHelper.ConvertToBoolean(((OracleParameter)p[5]).Value.ToString()),
            F
        };
        var errorNumber = ((OracleParameter)p[6]).Value.ToString();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(errorNumber) != 0)
        {
            //Nlog.logerror
            return "N";
        }
        return vLoginStatus;
```

My problem here is on database login status for validated user is Y, but I am not getting it and more than that i am not getting any outout paramter value back  in c#. How do I get database output parameter value in c#?

Comment: Any solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is using OracleHelper and HrOracleHelper which I do not know about. Are they custom class in your solution?

Comment: Are you sure you need to HtmlEncode the username and password? Maybe you don't get the Y because you ask for the wrong identity.

Comment: public static class HrOracleHelper
    {
        public static bool ConvertToBoolean(string oracleBool)
        {
            return oracleBool == "Y";
        }
    }  I created this class just to convert to boolean value and another OracleHelper[from metdadata]. i dont care about htmlencode and at the moment it is not encoding anything. I did not get you mean by that i am asking wrong identity, can you make more clear about this please?thanks

Comment: @shy set breakpoint on the method entry and go step by step over the lines of code, and see what is inside variables.